# node js multer file upload not working. req.file and req.files always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, multer

I am trying to upload a file to my server, but `req.file` and `req.files` is always undefined on my POST REST endpoint.

The content I'm trying to upload is a ".dat" file, and I am expecting a json response.

Here's my code:

**Server side:**

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/creoUpload', upload.single('uploadFileField'), function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("req.file = ",JSON.stringify(req.file)); //is undefined
  console.log("req.files = ",JSON.stringify(req.files)); //also undefined
});
```

**Client Side:**

```
<form id="creoUploadForm" action="/creoUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type='file' name='uploadFileField'><br><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Upload'/>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$( "#creoUploadForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
          url: '/creoUpload',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          async: true,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function (returndata) {
              console.log("RETURN DATA IS: ",returndata);
          },
          error: function (err) {
              console.log("ERROR: ",err);
          }
    });
});
```

I keep playing around with the fields but it's not working.. anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm following the example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

***Versions:***

- Express Version:  4.12.0
- Node Version:  6.5.0
- JQuery: 1.12.1

Thank you!

Comment: In your HTML, can you try removing the action from the form tag, and adding formaction="/creoupload" to the submit button?

Comment: try to send post request with `fetch` Api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using multer as a middleware, So before entering into your function and printing it has uploaded images to storage and removes record from *req.files*.

There are two ways you can access req.files.

1. Use multer as a function stated by *finw3*.
2. Another solution is:

//CODE STARTS

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({

  destination: function (req, file, cb) {

    cb(null, '/filepath')
  },


  filename: function (req, file, cb) {

    let filename = 'filenametogive';
     req.body.file = filename

    cb(null, filename)
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

//CODE ENDS

Now you can access files in req.body.file

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, if you check the documentation on the [Error Handling](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling) section there is another kind of implementation, that's the one that works for me. The code will be something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
var app = express();

app.post('/creoUpload', function(req, res, next) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // An error occurred when uploading
      console.log('Err: ', err);
      return;
    } else {
       console.log('req.file: ', JSON.stringify(req.file));  
       console.log('req.files: ', JSON.stringify(req.files));
       return;
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't set `contentType` to `false`, as POST method requires `contentType = 'w-xxx-form-urlencoded'`, which is the JQ default.

Answer (score 1):

If the `req.file` and `req.files` are `undefined`, then the problem is that **multer** did not receive the uploaded file and this issue seems related to `jQuery`.

Uploading a FormData with **jQuery 'v1.12.1' is not supported and it won't send anything at all.**
I will recommend to try with **fetch** Api or change the version of your jQuery to **3.3.1**.

I already tested the code and I have successfully upload a file to my server when I change my jQuery version from **v1.12.1** to **v3.3.1**.