# multer - req.file is undefined.

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am creating an app using Node, Express and Handlebars and multer for uploading images. Every time I submit the form, req.file is undefined. I've spent the entire day troubleshooting but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**Router File:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');


//Set Storage Engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/uploads/images',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + 
    path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
}).single('featuredImage');

//Change Featured Image - POST
router.post('/saveImage/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);

    //removed the rest of the code to keep it simple. req.file here is always undefined.

});
```

**Form**

```
<form action="/saveImage/{{pitch.id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="featuredImage">Featured Image</label>
         <input type="file" name="featuredImage" id="featuredImage">
     </div>

     <input type="submit" value="SAVE">
</form>
```

**app.js** these requires are in the app.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

//Set StaticFolder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: you need to add middleware for in api route.

Comment: as per git issues, even if you are using upload.single(), you will get file in `req.files` instead of `req.file` So try `req.files` and post back

Comment: @sidgujrathi You are wrong my friend. It will still be `req.file` [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#singlefieldname)

Comment: Yes, it will still be req.file. tries req.files anyway and it was undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `upload.single('featuredImage')` as middleware for the respective route as follows.

`const upload = multer({storage: storage});`

```
//Change Featured Image - POST
router.post('/saveImage/:id',upload.single('featuredImage'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);

   //removed the rest of the code to keep it simple. req.file here is always undefined.

});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I tried that but I get the error: TypeError: upload.single is not a function.

Comment: @Uzair you have to change `const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
}).single('featuredImage');` this to `const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
})`

Comment: Now I am getting the value of console.log(req.file), but I get the error that upload is not a function. Some improvement! haha thanks! :D

Comment: Fixed the issue. I was using an additional upload function which isn't required with upload.single('featuredImage'). Many thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was issue with image size. I resolved it with defining multer limit as follows:

```
const upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fieldSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 } }); //10MB
```

Took me ages to figured out.
Maybe this can help someone

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this question. It has answer you are looking for.

[node js multer file upload not working. req.file and req.files always undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958307/node-js-multer-file-upload-not-working-req-file-and-req-files-always-undefined/48961950#48961950)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass middleware

```
router.post('/saveImage/:id', upload.single('featuredImage'),  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I was having the same issue! But when I added this :

```js
const { storage } = require ('debug/src/browser');
```

... it worked.

This is my multer code :

```js
const { storage } = require('debug/src/browser');
 
const multer = require('multer');

const MINE_TYPES = {
'image/jpg' : 'jpg',

'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',

'image/png':'png'
}

const Storage = multer.diskstorage({

destination: (req, file, callback)=>{

callback(null, "public/images/articles")

},

filename: (req, file, callback) => {

var name = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(15258652325)).tostring() 

name = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(15258652325)).toString();

name = Math.floor (Math.random() * Math.floor(15258652325)).toString();

name = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(15258652325)).tostring();

name = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor 
(15258652325)).toString();

name += Date.now();

const extension = MINE_TYPES[file.mimetype]; 

name += extension;

callback(null,name);

module.exports = multer({ storage: Storage)). 
single('image');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and you can solve it by following these steps:

1- First add these line in your server.js or index.js root file

```
 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
  })
 );
```

2- Create a folder name middleware and inside it create a file name upload.js or any name that you want.

3- Place the following code in upload.js file

```
 const multer = require("multer");

 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function (req, file, cb) {
 cb(null, "public/");
},

 filename: function (req, file, cb) {
 const imgName = file.originalname;
 cb(null, imgName );
 },
});

 const upload = multer({
 storage: storage,
  });

module.exports = upload;
```

4- Now you can use this middleware in any route. For example:

```
const upload = require("../middlewares/fileUpload");

router.route("/send").post(upload.single("profile"), 
((req,res) => {
 *your controller logic here*
});


**Note: Here profile is the name of the file key that you are sending**
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
var fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(fileupload());
```