# how to upload images with cloudinary using multer memory storage?

Tags: javascript, typescript, upload, multer, cloudinary

Okay so i am uploading images with multer and saving it to cloudinary, that is basically the gist of it, It was working fine on local machine cause i was saving the pictures on my laptop using multer.diskStorage( ). Since i am deploying the application, i cant save it to local machine anymore so i wanted to use multer.memoryStorage( ) to only store it in memory while it saves to cloudinary, however, it is giving me a cloudinary error of 'Missing required parameter - file'. Even after checking the multer docs, I am not sure why it is not working.

This is the upload controller using cloudinary:

```
const upload = async (req, res) => {
    let fileData = [];
    if (req.files) {
        // Save image to cloudinary
        let uploadedFile 
        for(let i = 0; i< req.files.length; i++){
            try {
                const localFilePath = req.files[i].path
                uploadedFile = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(localFilePath, {
                    folder: "products",
                    resource_type: "image",
                })
                fileData.push({
                    fileName: req.files[i].originalname,
                    filePath: uploadedFile.secure_url,  //going to store only the cloudinary picture link to the db
                })

            } catch (error) {
                res.status(500);
                console.log(error)
                throw new Error('Image could not be Uploaded');
            }
        }
    }
    res.json(fileData) 
}
```

this is the upload function on the frontend:

```
    const handleImageUpload = async (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>, files:FileList | null) => {
        stopReload(e);
        if(files === null) {
            return;
        }
        setDragActive(false);
        setUploading(true)
        const data = new FormData()
        for(let i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
          data.append('images', files[i])
        }
        try {
            const {data:images} = await axios.post('/products/upload', data, {
            headers: {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}
            })
            setUploading(false)
            setAddedPhotos(prevState => [...prevState, ...images]) //would get the picture link and store it here to then add it to my db 
            console.log(addedPhotos)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    };
```

This is the multer function when it was working using diskStorage:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, 'uploads')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback){
        callback(null, uuidv4() + '-' + Date.now() + file.originalname)
    }
})

const fileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
    const allowedTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png']
    if(allowedTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        callback(null, true)
    }else(
        callback(null, false)
    )
}

const photoMiddleware = multer({storage, fileFilter})

module.exports = {photoMiddleware}
```

This is the multer function giving the error when storing in memory:

```
const storage = multer.memoryStorage()

const fileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
    const allowedTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png']
    if(allowedTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        callback(null, true)
    }else(
        callback(null, false)
    )
}

const photoMiddleware = multer({storage, fileFilter})

module.exports = {photoMiddleware}
```

the upload route:

```
router.route('/upload').post(photoMiddleware.array('images', 100), upload)
```

Comment: You may [check out the discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005446/multer-req-file-is-undefined) on how to upload files to your app endpoint through Multer. And from your app server side, you can upload file to Cloudinary using the Node SDK. Also, you may refer to some guidelines as [described in this document](https://andela.com/insights/how-to-use-cloudinary-and-nodejs-to-upload-multiple-images/) and this [link as well](https://www.codementor.io/@joejackson045/uploading-images-to-cloudinary-using-multer-and-expressjs-zthuy53oi).