Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path') when uploading files with Multer and Cloudinary
I’ve been following a tutorial from YouTube and encountered an error when trying to test my API with Thunder Client. Despite my debugging efforts, I haven’t been able to resolve it. I’d appreciate some help!
I’m getting the following error when testing my API:TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
cloudinaryConfig.js:
import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary';

const connectCloudinary = async () => {
    cloudinary.config({
        cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
        api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
        api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET_KEY,
    });
};
export default connectCloudinary;


multer.js:
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        // Specify the directory for storing uploaded files
        callback(null, path.resolve('./uploads'));
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        console.log("The file name is: ", file);
        // Use the original file name or customize it
        callback(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

export default upload;


adminRoute.js:
import express from 'express';
import { addDoctor } from '../controllers/adminController.js';
import upload from '../middlewares/multer.js';

const adminRouter = express.Router();

adminRouter.post('/add-doctor', upload.single('image'), addDoctor);

export default adminRouter;


adminController.js:
import validator from 'validator';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary';
import doctorModel from '../models/doctorModel.js';
import path from 'path';

const addDoctor = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, email, password, speciality, degree, experience, about, fees, address } = req.body;
        const imageFile = req.file;

        if (!name || !email || !password || !speciality || !degree || !experience || !about || !fees || !address) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Missing some details' });
        }

        if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Please enter a valid Email' });
        }

        if (password.length < 8) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Please, provide a strong password' });
        }

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        const imageUpload = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(imageFile.path, { resource_type: 'image' });
        const imageUrl = imageUpload.secure_url;

        const doctorData = {
            name,
            email,
            image: imageUrl,
            password: hashedPassword,
            speciality,
            degree,
            experience,
            about,
            fees,
            address: JSON.parse(address),
            date: Date.now(),
        };

        const newDoctor = new doctorModel(doctorData);
        await newDoctor.save();

        res.json({ success: true, message: 'Doctor added' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.json({ success: false, message: error.message });
    }
};

export { addDoctor };


When I send a POST request with a file (key: image) and form data, the doctor should be added successfully, and the image should be uploaded to Cloudinary.
I’m using Thunder Client to test the API.
The file upload key is named image.
What could be causing the path to be undefined in req.file?

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005446/multer-req-file-is-undefined

try with another agent. see similar issue involving thunder client: Why multer.diskStorage() is not called? p.s. add file error handler like with other fields

Is the file present before you try to upload it? Based on the error message you got, imageFile const is undefined. Try console.log(imageFile) before you upload it to cloudinary and see if imageFile is undefined or not
