# Express, Nodejs use Multer for different Services

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using express server and multer for upload file on different services (local, azure, cloudinary, amazon s3 etc).
For that i am using different module of multer multer-azure, multer-cloudinary etc.

I need this configuration will be applied to user wise and that information comes from the database.
So i need a extra call to fetch data from database before multer come in action.

I am able to call database query but when i am trying to call `multer` function, `req` parameter coming blank. Here is what i am doing.

```
var multerUtility = require('./upload/multer.utility');
let multer = new multerUtility().getActiveMulterService();
router.post('/', getMetadataConfiguration, multer, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('========== req ==========', req.file); // It is coming blank
  console.log('========== req ==========', req.body); // It is coming blank
});
```

Here is first middleware function, which fetch data from database to verifiy which service will use to upload file.

```
function getMetadataConfiguration(res, req, next) {
  var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    loginUrl : config.org_url,
  });
  var records = [];
  conn.login(username, password, function(err, userInfo) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
    conn.query("query", (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
      console.log('=========== result=========', result);
      req.serviceConfig = result.records[0];
      next();
    });
  });
}
```

And here is my MulterUtility Class to handle configuration:
`upload/multer.utility.js`

```
class MulterUtility {
  constructor() {
  }

  getActiveMulterService(req, res, next) {
    var multerConfiguration;
    if(req.serviceConfig.service == 'azure') {
      multerConfiguration = multer({
        storage: multerAzure({
          connectionString: config.azure.connectionString,
          account: config.azure.account,
          key: config.azure.key,
          container: config.azure.container
        })
      }).single('image');
    } else if(req.serviceConfig.service == 'cloudinary') {
      multerConfiguration = multer({
        storage: cloudinaryStorage({
          cloudinary: cloudinary,
          folder: config.storageFolder
          // allowedFormats: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']
        })
      }).single('image');
    } else if(req.serviceConfig.service === 'amazon') {
      multerConfiguration = multer({
        storage: multerS3({
          s3: s3,
          bucket: 'mycontainer',
          acl: 'public-read',
          contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
          metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
          },
          key: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, Date.now().toString() + '-' + file.originalname)
          }
        })
      }).single('image');
    } else if(req.serviceConfig.service === 'local') {
      multerConfiguration = multer({
        storage: multer.memoryStorage()
      }).single('image');
    }
    return multerConfiguration;
  }
}

module.exports = MulterUtility;
```

After executing multer, i am not recieving a req.file or req.body params what multer sets after uploading file.
For now you can consider the 'local' file upload as mentioned in last condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call the method `getActiveMulterService` once before the router. But you need to call it for each `post`. Try something like this:

```
var multerUtility = require('./upload/multer.utility');
let multers = new multerUtility();
router.post('/', 
    getMetadataConfiguration, 
    (req, res, next) => multers.getActiveMulterService(req, res, next)(req, res, next), 
    (req, res, next) => {
      console.log('========== req ==========', req.file); // It is coming blank
      console.log('========== req ==========', req.body); // It is coming blank
    });
```

And in this function you have arguments in the wrong order:

```
getMetadataConfiguration(res, req, next)
// ==>
getMetadataConfiguration(req, res, next)
```

Comment: i have updated the same, but after calling multer, the callback function is not calling, how can i fix this problem?

Comment: as getActiveMulterService() returning configuration, i am not calling next() from this function.

Comment: The `getActiveMulterService` function return `multerMiddleware`.

Comment: after executing getActiveMulterService(), callback function not calling. So i am unable to see console which we have added inside callback.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the multer as a result does not start. As a bad option - this is in the updated answer. On the good - the multer should not be returend, but run with parameters in function `getActiveMulterService`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this has largely been answered already. The solution is to manual add your file object back onto your req.body object during the process.

Full solution is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958307/node-js-multer-file-upload-not-working-req-file-and-req-files-always-undefined)